# JavaFX circular progressindicator not working as expected

Tags: java, javafx, progress-bar

So I'd like to make a circular progress indicator that runs smoothly from start to end, although I haven't found exactly what I'm looking for, I found a workaround using the class "ProgressIndicator" and grouping it in a way that is shown as I want it to.

I tried running this code that creates a timeline for it to do such smooth result I was looking for (this code isn't mine at all, took it from https://asgteach.com/2011/10/javafx-animation-and-binding-using-the-progressbar/) but it doesn't work as intended at all. The end result should be looking like this from start to end:
[expectation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qxnlg.png)

Although it takes some time to load showing this animation:
[reality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uV7l8.png)

Is there any way to make that starting animation not appear and make it so it starts instantly? If you have better options for what I'm trying to achieve or a solution using the existing progressIndicator I'm trying to use, I'll gladly hear them out.

The code I'm trying to run right now:

```
private static final Integer STARTTIME = 30;
private Timeline timeline;
private IntegerProperty timeSeconds = new SimpleIntegerProperty(STARTTIME*100);

public void testProgressIndicator() {
    myProgressIndicator.progressProperty().bind(
            timeSeconds.divide(STARTTIME*100.0).subtract(1).multiply(-1));
    btnTest.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            if (timeline != null) {
                timeline.stop();
            }
            timeSeconds.set((STARTTIME+1)*100);
            timeline = new Timeline();
            timeline.getKeyFrames().add(

                    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(STARTTIME+1),
                    new KeyValue(timeSeconds, 0)));
            timeline.playFromStart();
        }
    });
```

Comment: You don’t show how you initialize the progress indicator.  If you just call the noarg constructor it will start in an indeterminate state with a spinning animation.  If you provide the initial progress as a constructor argument, it will start in an inanimate state with that progress. Study the [javadoc](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ProgressIndicator.html) and check your code.

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: @jewelsea I took a good look at the progress property and in the end I figured out what was happening, there was a +1 at line 14 of the code I posted that was making the progress start with negative number, thus starting that spinning animation until it turned positive. The constructor was not the problem, since I used SceneBuilder to set its initial properties as I desired. Thanks again for suggesting the progress indicator, that lead me to look for the actual problem.